# base64 to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, react-native, buffer, espruino

Am trying to decode a base64 string containing an array buffer. After decoding all am getting is a string showing [object ArrayBuffer]. However I need the actual ArrayBuffer

base64 -  W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0=

library am using decoding  - [react-native-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-base64)

Comment: You mean like when doing "new Int8Array(buffer)"?

Comment: @RaniSharim Yes basically I need an array buffer I can use int8Array() on to access its data

Comment: Seems like you encoded wrong. You encoded the sting "[object ArrayBuffer]", that's why the decode is giving you that. Try in in online decoders and you'll see.

Comment: @Rani thanks your are right my encoding was wrong I encoded the string [object ArrayBuffer]